# How to check DDL Events Properties for ADD_ROLE_MEMBER event

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

how to check/find event properties of a DDL Event?

I want to capture Role name on event ADD_ROLE_MEMBER and DROP_ROLE_MEMBER 
something like this

```
EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/RoleName)[1]',  'nvarchar(256)')
```

but how to know which properties are available against these event types?

I am using Sql Server 2016/2017/2019. Thank you.

```
Select * from sys.event_notification_event_types
Where parent_type=10032
```

Query Output:

```
parent_type type    name
10029       10032   |   |   |   DDL_ROLE_EVENTS
10032       208     |   |   |   |   DROP_ROLE_MEMBER
10032       207     |   |   |   |   ADD_ROLE_MEMBER
10032       136     |   |   |   |   DROP_ROLE
10032       135     |   |   |   |   ALTER_ROLE
10032       134     |   |   |   |   CREATE_ROLE
```

like if you visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms179312(v=sql.90)
you can get to know event properties and inherited event properties of only `CREATE_ROLE, ALTER_ROLE, DROP_ROLE` but now info is missing about `ADD_ROLE_MEMBER, DROP_ROLE_MEMBER` since documentation is of SQL Server 2005 and event properties details are not mentioned with Sql Server 2017/2019 documentation.
The properties are like `TSQLCommand (string), PostTime (datetime), ObjectName (string)` etc.

Comment: Are you after [DDL Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Yes its DDL Events

Comment: It's really not obvious or intuitive, but this is "documented" in [the XML schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/events.xsd) (`EVENT_INSTANCE_ADD_ROLE_MEMBER`, `EVENT_INSTANCE_DROP_ROLE_MEMBER`).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert the XML schema link helped alot, but i also find out that EVENTDATA() function will also throw all possible values available in an Event without data types.